# try/catch a void type

Tags: java, junit, try-catch, void

I am new to programming and have a noob question.  I am trying to run a test like so...

```
@Test
public void rememberTest()
throws DuplicateException{

    try{
        personA.remember(sighting4);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Failed" + e.getMessage());
    }
    try{
        assertEquals(personA.remember(sighting3), "The list already contains this sighting");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Failed" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

the first try/catch compiles but the second one does not.  It tells me "'void' type not allowed here. 
" Why can't I  use a void? If I can't use a void type, then how would I build my test so that the exception is thrown?

some background info: rememberTest is a test of the remember method that adds an item to an ArrayList.

the remember method, in Class Person, is as follows:

```
public void remember(final Sighting s)
throws DuplicateException
{
    if(lifeList.contains(s)) {
        throw new DuplicateException("The list already contains this sighting");
    }
    lifeList.remember(s); 
}
```

If you need more info please request and I will post it as required.

Comment: What is the return type of `remember` method?

Comment: **personA.remember(sighting3)** must have a void return. you cannot have a void type as parameter for another method.

Comment: Hey Samngeeth, the type for remember is void

Comment: @nafas  So how would I build this method so that the exception is thrown? This is the info that i am after.

Comment: @user3738926 update your question and include **remember** method

Comment: @user3738926 I believe the best approach is to do this assert inside the method itself

Comment: @nafas method is posted

Comment: @nafas  I require the exception to be thrown in the test class.  If the code is not tested, it is no good to me.

Comment: well you have already covered that. I don't think using assertEquals is suitable in this case, because your method already ensures that you won't add any duplicates,

Comment: nafas, I know what you're saying, and I agree. However, this is an assignment, and I require a passing test that throws the exception.  What would be suitable for this purpose?

Comment: @user3738926 Does your assigment requires you to use assertEqual or to throw exception, they are two different concept

Comment: I need a test that shows that the the exception is thrown.  How I get there matters less.  I just used assertEquals to try to show this.

Comment: @user3738926 then look at the answer I provided, you just don't need to use assertEqual, so personA.remember(sighting3) WILL throw Exception IF sighting3 already is in lifeList (I'm guessing this is a list of some sort)

Comment: @nafas  but I don't want to just throw the exception. I want to throw the exception AND have a passing test based on the exception thrown. Understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you method has already ensured that no duplicate value will be added then I suggest to remove the `assertEquals` from your code,

```
@Test
public void rememberTest()
throws DuplicateException{

    try{
        personA.remember(sighting4);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Failed" + e.getMessage());
    }
    try{
        personA.remember(sighting3), //this will throws Exception if sighting3 is already in.
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Failed" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

to demonstrate edit your code to this:

```
@Test
public void rememberTest()
throws DuplicateException{

    Sighting s1=//initialize s1
    Sighting s2=s1;
    try{
        personA.remember(s1);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Failed" + e.getMessage());
    }
    try{
        personA.remember(s2), //This will throw an exception because s1 and s2 are pointed to the same object
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Failed" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: nafas, look at it like this: Suppose sighting3 and sighting4 are the same.  I want to add sighting3, and then add sighting4, and show in testing that the DuplicateException is thrown.

Comment: This is what I mean mate, sighting3 and sighting4 may be a refrence to same object, if this is the case then the code will throw the exception. literally speaking: sighting3 and sighting4 are both references to some objects.what matters the most is the object itself not the references

Comment: I did solve it and you helped me work through it.  Thanks nafas.          try{
            personA.remember(sightingSame);
        }
        catch (DuplicateException e) {
            assertEquals("The list already contains this sighting", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Failed" + e.getMessage());
        }

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of doing assert you should use the @Expected annotation which expects for the DuplicateException since its a test case

Answer (score 0):

for the purpose of throwing the exception and catching it in the test Class, do some such thing as this:

```
 try{
            personA.remember(sightingSame);
        }
        catch (DuplicateException e) {
            assertEquals("The list already contains this sighting", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Failed" + e.getMessage());
        }
```